# How to update a subset of rows based on certain column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that returns a order set of data based con CBU and DATE(Fecha)

```
SELECT 
    cta.CODIGO, cta.cbu, cta.fecha
FROM
    CUENTA_BANCARIA as CTA
WHERE
    (CTA.ESTADO = 1) and (CTA.HABILITADA = 1)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT C.* 
                FROM CUENTA_BANCARIA as C 
                WHERE (C.CODIGO != CTA.CODIGO) 
                  AND (C.NRO_CTA =  CTA.NRO_CTA) 
                  AND (C.CBU = CTA.CBU) 
                  AND (C.ESTADO = 1) 
                  AND (C.HABILITADA = 1))
ORDER BY
    CTA.CBU, CTA.FECHA DESC
```

I need to update any `CUENTA_BANCARIA` with the same CBU which does not have the latest DATE (FECHA)

For example, for the given results I need to update the CUENTA_BANCARIA with codigo highlighted in orange, since all of them have the same CBU but older DATE (FECHA)

How can I create such query ?

[image]

Comment: Look at using RowNumber() with a PARTITION BY clause.

Comment: You need to update to the latest date, right?

Comment: @Hackerman I need to update all the records wich are NOT the latest date of that "subset" with the same CBU

Comment: But what field you need to update and with, what value?

Comment: @Hackerman the field is "HABILITADA = 0"

Answer (score 0):

Following @pmbAustin sugestion about `RowNumber` and `Partition By` here is the solution

```
update cb
set cb.HABILITADA = 0
from CUENTA_BANCARIA cb
where cb.codigo in (
select SubQuery.codigo
(SELECT cta.CODIGO, cta.NRO_CTA, cta.cbu, cta.fecha, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY CTA.cbu order by CTA.fecha desc) as numRepetido
from CUENTA_BANCARIA as CTA
where 
(CTA.ESTADO = 1) and (CTA.HABILITADA = 1)
and 
exists (SELECT C.* FROM CUENTA_BANCARIA as C where (C.CODIGO != CTA.CODIGO) and (C.NRO_CTA =  CTA.NRO_CTA) and (C.CBU = CTA.CBU) and (C.ESTADO = 1) and (C.HABILITADA = 1))) as SubQuery
where SubQuery.numRepetido != 1)
```